# Delphi XE3 indy gmail smtp

Tags: delphi, gmail, indy, delphi-xe3

I have a problem sending gmail smtp mail with indy on delphi XE3 build (Version 17.0.4770.56661)

I can smooth send my laptop but other pc's give a error like "connection closed gracefully"

I add a idlogfile component on my form and give me this line

```
Recv 18.04.2013 11:17:20: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP s47sm13947715eeg.8 - gsmtp<EOL>
Sent 18.04.2013 11:17:20: EHLO S23-101<EOL>
Recv 18.04.2013 11:17:20: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [195.175.87.XX]<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>
Sent 18.04.2013 11:17:20: STARTTLS<EOL>
Recv 18.04.2013 11:17:21: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
Sent 18.04.2013 11:17:21: QUIT<EOL>
```

And I use this code on my app

```
IdSMTP1.host:='smtp.gmail.com'  ;
    IdSMTP1.username:='umutscada@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP1.Password:='XXXX';
    IdSMTP1.port:=587;
    IdSMTP1.UseTLS:=utUseExplicitTLS;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method:= sslvTLSv1;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 2;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Host := IdSMTP1.Host;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Port := IdSMTP1.Port;

    IdMessage1.From.address := 'umutscada@gmail.com';
    IdMessage1.CClist.EMailAddresses:= edit5.Text;
    IdMessage1.Subject:= 'Subject is here';
    IdMessage1.Body.Clear;
    Idmessage1.Body.Add('Body is here');
    for Z := 0 to ListBox8.Items.Count-1 do begin
      TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts,ListBox8.Items[Z]);
    end;
    IdSMTP1.Connect;
    IdSMTP1.Authenticate;
    try
        try
            idSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
        except on E:Exception do
            Memo1.Lines.Insert(0, 'ERROR: ' + E.Message);
        end;
    finally
        if idSMTP1.Connected then idSMTP1.Disconnect;
    end;
```

Please help me

Thanks :)

Comment: for what i remember, GMail pop interfaces demand using SSL/TLS. Check that firewall or antivirus does not kill encrypted mail traffic (had issues with Avira). Check that date, time and timezone are set correctly.

Comment: Hi arioch, I use not any firewall or antivirus and i try a lot of pc

Answer (score 0):

When a `QUIT` command is sent immediately after the `STARTTLS` response is received, that means an exception was raised during the actual SSL/TLS handshake.  `TIdSMTP.Connect()` catches the exception, calls `Disconnect()` (sending an unencrypted `QUIT` since SSL/TLS is not active <sup>1</sup>), and then re-raises the exception into your code.  So you need to check what exception is actually being raised.  A "connection closed gracefully" exception means the connection was closed on the other end, either by the server itself, or maybe by a firewall/router that is sitting in the middle of the connection.

---

**Update:**

<sup>1</sup>: `TIdSMTP` was updated in SVN rev 5156 in 2014 to no longer send an unencrypted `QUIT` when closing the socket due to a SSL/TLS handshake failure, since the socket is in an indeterminate state by that point.

Answer (score -1):

You must **"Allow less secure applications access yoputr account"** in the configuration of your account. Google hacve added some restrictions in this way.

[See this link in Google documentation.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: No, you *do not* need to enable the "Allow less secure applications" option. You can instead have Google generate an application-specific password and then you can use that password with Indy instead of your normal Gmail password. But either way, this is not the cause of the OP's problem, as the failure is occurring during the TLS handshake before SMTP authentication is performed.